# R Shiny: Make radiobuttons impacts other input

Tags: r, shiny

I am making something i Shiny and am wondering whether it is possible to make radiobuttons decide another input.

A toy example that replicates my problem is given by:

```
if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",
                 c("Normal" = "norm",
                   "Uniform" = "unif")),
     textInput(inputId = "textid", label = "Text input-header", value = "rnorm"),
    plotOutput("distPlot")
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    df <- reactive({
      switch(input$textid, 
             rnorm = {rnorm(500)},
             uni = {runif(500)}, 
             exp = {rexp(500)},
      )})

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot(hist(df())
    )
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

As it is now, it is the input in the text box that decides what kind of distribution, that is used to generate the data. What I would like is that when one clicks of one of the radio buttons then the text is updated in the text box (e.g. if "Uniform" is checked off, then the textunput is updated with "uni" - and thereby this distribution is used). The thing is that I need the box since I would like to be able to choose somethiong that is not an option among the radio buttons (so it does not work for me just to add extra radio buttons). The extra option in this case is, that one can write "exp" in the text input (this distribution cannot be chosen from a radio button).

It might seem a bit idiotic in this example, but in my case I have 2 very often used timestamps, but the app must allow the user to choose every possible date as well.

Is this somehow possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Note that I added the `req` where it is required to have your text input as one of `"rnorm","uni","exp"`

```
library(shiny)
if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",c("Normal" = "rnorm","Uniform" = "uni","Exponential" = "exp")),
    textInput(inputId = "textid", label = "Text input-header", value = "rnorm"),
    plotOutput("distPlot")
  )

  server <- function(input, output,session) {

    observeEvent(input$dist,{
      updateTextInput(session, "textid",label = "Text input-header",value = input$dist)

    })

    df <- eventReactive(input$textid,{
      req(input$textid %in%c("rnorm","uni","exp"))
      switch(input$textid, rnorm = {rnorm(500)},uni = {runif(500)}, exp = {rexp(500)},
      )})
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot(hist(df()))
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! (without the exponential radio button, this is exactly, what I wanted!) 
THANKS!